# What are the limitations on using SSRS with SQL Server 2005 Express edition?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-express

I found [this](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/technologies/reporting/rsfeatures.mspx) extremely old document which appears to say that many of the web client features are not availiable when running on express edition--scheduling, subscription, etc--as well as no access to the report builder. Is that information still current, and are there any other features which are unavailable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscriptions and scheduling are indeed absent in both MSSQLEx2005 and MSSQLEx2008, but I have never found this to be much of a problem. The underlying platform has a scheduler and the web service will do all the rendering, so you can recreate the missing elements without too much trouble.

The report builder is also absent, and *this* is non-trivial to replicate. You could always install SQLEx locally and let them use BIDS. Or you could stop being cheap. It's pretty good for free.

---

I recommend you use SSRS2008 rather than 2005 because it no longer requires IIS, and there are several sexy new capabilities in the report engine. In particular it now supports flow-based rich text with inline fields for mail-merge type reports.

Compatibility is excellent but some applications reject a newer database engine version. If this is a problem, continue to use SQLExpr2005 for the database.

> So, are you saying that A) SSRS 2005
>   requires IIS whereas 2008 does not,
>   and that B) SSRS2008 is backwards
>   compatible with a SQL2005 database?
>   (It sounds like you might be saying
>   that SSRS 2008 could be used with
>   somebody running 2005 DBs

Yes, I am indeed saying that

- SSRS 2005 requires IIS whereas 2008 does not
- SSRS 2008 is backwards compatible with a SQL2005 database
- SSRS 2008 could be used with somebody running 2005 DBs, or even 2000 DBs.

You can use SSRS with any database server for which ADO.NET drivers are available, including Oracle and MySQL.

Comment: So, are you saying that A) SSRS 2005 requires IIS whereas 2008 does not, and that B) SSRS2008 is backwards compatible with a SQL2005 database? (It sounds like you might be saying that SSRS 2008 could be used with somebody running 2005 DBs)

Answer (score 0):

I've caught somewhere the idea about rich text in SSRS 2008. 
As I see it will allow me to make such static text

"Some test with some text in **bold** and some *italic* text"

with a single text box which was impossible in RS 2005. (even don't know good way to make it there)

You wrote it doesn't require SQL Server 2008 to be installed. 
What about IDE for reports development ?

Looking forward with big hopes for SSRS 2008,
thanks for attention in advance,
Alex